# Scheduling in a webpage release

Tags: html, css

I have just started to learn html and css and curious to know if there's a way of scheduling changes to html code.

To give you guys an idea of what I am looking to do...

I am building a one page website that displays a quote or comment. I want this to change every day and wondered if there's a way of scheduling  in that change so I don't have to change it at the start of every day.

Helps to make life a little easier for me!

Thanks so much

Tom

Comment: Your question is too broad. You need to try something and come back when you have a specific coding problem. In general you could use JavaScript to do what you want, or a server side language like PHP.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. To expand on j08691's comment, check out the [help/on-topic] for what you can ask here - also relevant is [ask]. Stack Overflow has a pretty specific focus in order to remain a useful resource for future users.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I will start to have a look at it with your advice and get more specific when I need further help!

Answer (score 1):

@TDS, you can do this with javascript, by using a loop and setting a time/date delay, you would eventually have to maintain it though, i.e update the quotes you are using. As far as i am aware it is not possible to schedule changes automatically with html/css.
Have a look here for inspiration: [Changing HTML dynamically](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-way-to-make-automatically-changing-quotes-in-the-header-of-my-website-using-HTML-CSS-and-JS)

Comment: Thanks a lot for getting back to me and the link! Will take a look and keep you posted!

Comment: @TDS did this answer your question, if so mark it as answered please